# showing images in autocomplete results

Tags: php, jquery

I stored image URLs in column B of my database and hope to show them in picture form in autocomplete results. I tried to compose the code as follows, but it simply gives the URLs in text format. What can I do to solve it? Many thanks.

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("input[name='search']").autocomplete({
                        source:'search.php',
                        minLength:1
                    });
                });
        </script>

<input type="text" name="search" required/>
```

**search.php**

```
$keyterms = $_GET['term'];
$query = $database->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE A LIKE '%".$keyterms."%'    ORDER BY A ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['B'];}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: you want show image in autocomplete?

Comment: Yup. show the images but not their URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
$keyterms = $_GET['term'];
$query = $database->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE A LIKE '%".$keyterms."%'    ORDER BY A ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
$data[] = '<a href="' . $row['B'] . '"></a>';}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Note: is it not final solution, but hint for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom view for your autocomplete, check here example [custom data and display autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Answer (score 0):

[You can have a label and a value when using autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

```
$keyterms = $_GET['term'];
$query = $database->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE A LIKE '%".$keyterms."%'    ORDER BY A ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = [
        'value' => $row['B']
        ,'label' => '<img src="' . $row['imgurl'] . '">'
    ];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

And the page should just handle it

Comment: And you should be sure to escape $_GET['term'] before sticking it in that string. You're vulnerable to SQL injection